# How to disable debug mode in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Debug mode is really getting annoying. How do I disable it, it just popped out of nowhere. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you check whether debug=true or something similar is passed to the application when launching? You can check the properties of the shortcut used to launch chrome.

Comment: very helpful comment. I don't even know what you're talking about

Comment: What version of chrome is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not part of Chrome (the bad grammar should have tipped you off). That is a JQuery form-validation notice.

Normally, it is only enabled when designing and testing a website and disabled in production code. Contact the website’s admins/webmasters/etc. and let them know about the error.